# list of country/stats/town + count

Tags: php, mysql, listview, count

i have three table for my_location1 & my_location2 & my_location3 . `my_ is Prefix` . location1 = countrylist . location2 = statslist . location3 = townlist . in other table i have userlist . now i want to list all Location (country - stats - town) using tree styles + aqual user in each country stats town (count). ( How To Generate This ?? )

Databse NOTE : pid & pid1 = id of country, pid2 = id of stats

my_location1 :

```
id ++++++ name ++++++ active
```

my_location2 :

```
id ++++++ pid +++++++ name ++++++ active
```

my_location3 :

```
id ++++++ pid1 +++++++ pid2 ++++++ name ++++++ active
```

my_user

```
id ++++++ name ++++++ location1 ++++++ location2 ++++++ location3 ++++++ active
```

e.x

```
Country (print count Of users in this country )
+++++++stats (print count Of users in this stats )
++++++++++++town (print count Of users in this town )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
+++++++stats ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
+++++++stats ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
Country1 ( ... )
+++++++stats ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
Country2 ( ... )
+++++++stats ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
++++++++++++town ( ... )
...more
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: i want to list all Location (country - stats - town) using tree styles + aqual user in each country stats town (count). ( How To Generate This ?? )

Comment: Depends on which treeview control you want to use. Did you already select a treeview control eg. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/ ?

Comment: i need to print this using php/mysql without jquery.

Comment: Ok, so how do you want your result look like? A table, nested ul/li elements, or..? `Tree style + aqual` is not a common sense for me.

Comment: Sure `ul+li` elements is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the code, but it should be something like this:

```
function getCountries()
{
   return mysql_query('SELECT c.*, (COUNT(*) from u WHERE u.location1 = c.id) AS user_count
                           from countrylist c
                           LEFT JOIN users u
                           ON u.location1 = c.id
                           WHERE c.active = 1'
                        );
}

function getStats($countryId)
{
   return mysql_query('SELECT s.*, (COUNT(*) from u WHERE s.location2 = s.id) AS user_count
                           from statslist s
                           LEFT JOIN users u
                           ON u.location2 = s.id
                           WHERE s.pid = ' . $countryId
                        );   
}

function getTowns($stateId)
{
   return mysql_query('SELECT t.*, (COUNT(*) from u WHERE t.location3 = t.id) AS user_count
                           from townlist
                           LEFT JOIN users u
                           ON u.location3 = t.id
                           WHERE t.pid2 = ' . $stateId
                        );   
}

echo "<ul>\n";
while ($country = mysql_fetch_assoc(getCountries())) {
    echo "<li>" . $country["name"] . "(" . $country["user_count"] . ")\n";
    echo "<ul>\n";

    while ($state = mysql_fetch_assoc(getStats($country["id"]))) {
      echo "<li>" . $state["name"] . "(" . $state["user_count"] . ")\n<ul>\n";
      while ($town = mysql_fetch_assoc(getTowns($state["id"]))) {
         echo "<li>" . $town["name"] . "(" . $town["user_count"] . ")</li>\n";
      }
      echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    }

    echo "<ul>\n</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

It could and should be further optimized, but hope you get the idea. Please also note that your mysql structure is quite redundant.